# How can I check if one subquery is a subset of another subquery in Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Is it possible to create a query in Oracle SQL that selects only elements such that a subquery is a subset of another subquery?

For example:

```
select Foo.f
from Foo
where

    --The set of all Bar.b's where Foo.f=Bar.b
    (select Bar.b
    from Bar
    where Foo.f = Bar.b)

    contains 

    --The set of all Bar.b's where Bar.c=10
    (select Bar.b
    from Bar
    where Bar.c=10);
```

Or "select all Foo.f where, all Bar.b with Bar.c=10 is a subset of all Bar.b where Foo.f=Bar.b"?

[EDIT] So here may be a better way of phrasing what I'm asking. 
If there are two subqueries in a where statement which return subsets A and B, how can I check that B is a subset of A. So to rewrite the initial example in a more generic way:

```
Select Foo.f
from Foo
where
    --Subset A
    (select ...)

    ?? Some set comparison operator

    --Subset B
    (select ...)
```

Comment: I don't clearly understand your question. The answers below are also quite spread. Can you provide a more clear example with testdata please? Please also look up keywords like `with`, `exists`, `inner join` and `intersect`(from current answers) with oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I believe I found an answer. 
First, note that if B ⊆ A then B-A = ∅

Then, using only SQL set operators, I can do

```
select Foo.f
from Foo
where
    not exists (
        --Subset B
        (select...)

        minus

        --Subset A
        (select...));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple `AND` within a `EXISTS` query should work.

```
select foo.f
from Foo  where exists ( select 1 from Bar  where Foo.f = Bar.b and Bar.c = 10 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Huh, you wrote quite a lot of code for something that I interpreted as simple

```
select Foo.f
from Foo join Bar on Foo.f = Bar.b
where Bar.c = 10
```

Comment: I suppose this does work for this particular question. But im asking more generally. Bad example on my part. I’ll try to come up with better wording..